# Showing a property using Jacobians

Tags: calculus

Show that $\left(\displaystyle\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}\right)\left(\displaystyle\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,s)}\right)=\displaystyle\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (r,s)}$. Thus, prove that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}=\frac{1}{\displaystyle\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}}$

---

I have no idea on how to get started with this problem. I tried attacking it down with Jacobians, but to no avail. I'm not even sure how did they define the systems in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: Let  $A, B, C$ be $m \times m $ matrices such that $A \times B= C$, then $detC= detA \cdot detB$.

Proof: By lemma, it's sufficient to show that $$ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}& \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial r}& \frac{\partial v}{\partial s} \end{pmatrix}$$

However, it is directly given by the chain rule, since according to the chain rule, regarding (u,v) as the composition of (x,y) and (r,s), we have, for example
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$$ And other three can be checked as well. 
Therefore we have $$ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}& \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial r}& \frac{\partial v}{\partial s} \end{pmatrix}$$
Thus $(\displaystyle\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)})(\displaystyle\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,s)})=\displaystyle\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (r,s)}$

Comment: That is a pretty nice solution, however it is based on an assumption. We require this assumption to solve this proble, or can it be solved without making it?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$u_1=u, u_2=v, x_1=x, x_2=y, r_1=r, r_2=s$$ Here I'll use the symbol you use for the determinant for the matrix itself, that is:
$$\left(\frac{\partial (a_1, a_2)}{\partial (b_1,b_2)}\right)_{ij}:=\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial b_i}$$
Then
$$\left(\left(\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,s)}\right)\left(\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}\right)\right)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^2\left(\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial r_i}\right)\left(\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_k}\right) = \left(\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial r_i}\right)=\left(\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (r,s)}\right)_{ij}$$
so that there is an equality of the Jacobian matrices:
$$\left(\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,s)}\right)\left(\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}\right)=\left(\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (r,s)}\right)$$
Notice the order of multiplication. Our matrix could be the transposed of the one I defined, which would change the order.  Nevertheless, take the deteterminant from both sides and you get the first result. Take $$r=x, s=y$$ and you get the second